# Parental Controls always asks permission when browsing websites

Tags: parental-controls

I don't want to add some websites, but Parental Controls always asks permission when browsing them. 
Are there any solution to fix this issue? How can I just block them?
Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with your hosts file, if you are comfortable using terminal

### Manually

1. Open Terminal
2. Type `sudo nano /etc/hosts` then hit return
3. Tap the down arrow to move your cursor below the line that says `127.0.0.1 localhost`
4. Type in `127.0.0.1` and then the address of the site you want to block, making sure to keep a space between the numbers and the address. For example, `127.0.0.1 facebook.com` will block Facebook, or `127.0.0.1 google.ca`.
5. You must do this for any name it may resolve to, for example, if it was google, you must to `127.0.0.1 google.ca` and `127.0.0.1 www.google.ca` and every other resolver: `127.0.0.1 www.facebook.com` and `127.0.0.1 facebook.com` would need to be entered into the hosts file.
6. To exit nano, you must press `control (^)` + `x` then `Y` then `return / enter`
7. Type `sudo dscacheutil -flushcache` do restart dns services. This will activate your changes.

### Automatic Blocking

You could do this at the DNS level instead, resulting in no bypass available unless they have the administrative password. 
[CleanBrowsing](https://cleanbrowsing.org/getting-started) is one of many services that allow for blocking at this level. See [IP address list](https://cleanbrowsing.org/ip-address) and [Setup Instructions](https://cleanbrowsing.org/macos) for more info.

Basically, if the user goes to any site CleanBrowsing deems inappropriate, it will block it, and make it so it will not resolve (identify the domain to the correct IP address) to go to the correct website, and will instead display a page saying that "this address is blocked" or something to that result.

The DNS Addresses are as follows

> **Family Filter**
>
> *Blocks access to all adult, pornographic and explicit sites. It also
>   blocks proxy and VPN domains that are used to bypass the filters.
>   Mixed content sites (like Reddit) are also blocked. Google, Bing and
>   Youtube are set to the Safe Mode.*

```
> IPv4 address: 185.228.168.168 and 185.228.168.169 
> IPv6 address: 2a0d:2a00:1:: and 2a0d:2a00:2::
```

> **Adult Filter**
>
> *Blocks access to all adult, pornographic and explicit sites. It does
>   not block proxy or VPNs, nor mixed-content sites. Sites like Reddit
>   are allowed. Google and Bing are set to the Safe Mode.*

```
> IPv4 address: 185.228.168.10 and 185.228.168.11 
> IPv6 address: 2a0d:2a00:1::1 and 2a0d:2a00:2::1
```

> **Security Filter**
>
> *Blocks access to phishing, malware and malicious domains. It does not
>   block adult content.*

```
> IPv4 address: 185.228.168.9 and 185.228.169.9 
> IPv6 address: 2a0d:2a00:1::2 and 2a0d:2a00:2::2
```

Setup for this is as follows:

```
1. Open System preferences
2. Go to Network > Select the interface being used
3. Click Advanced
4. Click DNS
5. Remove any old listings, as they are likely to be used for resolving first.
6. Press the ``+`` button located in the bottom left, then add the desired servers.
```

> Please note to use the servers listed above, both the IPv4 and IPv6 addresses.